# RubyMine Folder Tree doesn't refresh

Tags: rubymine

Using RubyMine 2.0.2 for the first time today, on Mac OSX Leopard.  If I create files in the filesystem (with, say, script/generate) those new files do not appear in rubymine.  I have had limited success with restarting the program, in that the files in the db/ folder are added and removed, but unfortunately new folders in the views directory are not shown.

Pardon my french, but wtf?

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

I'm experiencing the same, couple of things seem to work ...
Close rubymine, delete the .idea folder ...

```
sudo rm -r .idea
```

(if macos or linux)

... and restart until they fix it

AND/OR

In Rubymine, Go to File > Open Directory > navigate to the directory or file that you require, this should refresh the view, don't add the .idea folder to git ( if you're using it )

Not great, but you can get round it

Answer (score 11):

If you right click on a directory in the Projects tab, there is an option for "Synchronize". Click it and RM will show all files, sub-diretories etc. again.