# Folders not visible in RubyMine

Tags: rubymine

I am using RubyMine 8.0.3, I have **3 folders and 2 `.rb`** files in `controller/api/v1` , **none out of 3 folders are visible** but **both `.rb` files are visible**. I reopened the the IDE but nothing happened. I also tried the solutions mentioned in the following link: [RubyMine Folder Tree doesn't refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796739/rubymine-folder-tree-doesnt-refresh)

Note:

1: When I open my project in sublime all folders are visible.

2: I have added .idea/ in my .gitignore file.

Comment: try deleting your `.idea` folder

Answer (score 13):

I couldn't find the source of the problem, but deleting the `.idea/` folder worked for me.

Comment: This works! Thanks for it!

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me too. Had to do it a few times thought.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar incident, but did not want to delete the `.idea` folder. After poking in the Preferences, I found that under Project Structure, the content root had gone missing. After clicking `Add Content Root` and double-clicking the root folder of the code, the subfolders are now visible.

Hope this helps others as it looks like you found the solution!

Comment: This happened to me after update from beta to RubyMine 2021.1. Fixed by this setting.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are using the [Rails view](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.1/rails-view.html) in the Project tool window? This view can sometimes mask some files. If so, switch the tool back to the Project view. Also, check that you have not excluded the directories in the [Project structure settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.1/project-structure.html#d558390e238).

Answer (score 0):

In my case folders were empty that is why it was not visible, not sure why.
As soon as I added(from terminal) some file to it. It started showing.